# svgPath.getTotalLength() crashes safari on particular path

Tags: javascript, svg, safari, path, webkit

Trying to figure out why safari simply just chokes and crashes while evaluating the total length of a specific path... I've tried to remove certain points from the path to try and break down the issue. It works on every other browser I've tested so far.

Here is the code running in it:

```js
var myPath = document.getElementById("word");
var length = myPath.getTotalLength();
alert(length);
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 5000 5000" xml:space="preserve">
  <path id="word" stroke="#000000" fill="none" stroke-width="20" d="M3045.44,2522.588c-0.73,0.432-1.927,0.575-2.438,0.568 c-1.12-0.01-4.15-0.989-5.847-0.917c-0.543,0.021,0.176-0.286,0.355-0.343c1.537-0.473,5.494-1.193,7.539-0.701 C3046.408,2521.523,3046.107,2522.196,3045.44,2522.588z"/>
</svg>
```

Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=349873

**EDIT:**

Created a WebKit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=173566

Comment: If it crashes on Safari, why have you raised a Chrome bug? You need to raise a [webkit bug](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/). If you want to know why, download the source, build it with debug and step through it.

Comment: I didn't raise the chrome bug.. it's just a related issue in Chrome that I found. Sorry, I should have been more clear?

Comment: It could be an old webkit bug that has been fixed in Chrome, but not Safari.  I suggest you check the Safari bug tracker to see if it is listed and if not, report it..